# Running multiple PHP script at once with register_shutdown_function

Tags: php, url

I am using the following code capture different URLs:

```
        $array_URLs = array();        
        $x=1;
        while(isset($_POST['URL'.$x])){
            $array_URLs[] = $_POST['URL'.$x];
            $x++;
        }
```

After that I run the following code so I can execute a function before the script ends:

```
register_shutdown_function(array('Export', 'myExportFuncion'));
```

Now I need to run each URL given in the $array_URLs as it was called from the web browser. However I need to execute myExportFuncion only when all URLs are executed. I am trying to use the following code to achieve this:

```
    foreach($array_URLs as $URL){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    }
```

The above code does not generate the expected result. What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: What you need to do and what are you expecting as output... and use `extract($_POST)` instead of the first section

Comment: You could use Guzzle for async requests: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests

Comment: What is _expected result_? AND What result do you get?  Those are kind of important here.